# Sending C# object to webapi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to pass a C# object to a web api controller. The api is configured to store objects of type Product that are posted to it. I have successfully added objects using Jquery Ajax method and now I'm trying to get the same result in C#.

I've created a simple Console application to send a Post request to the api:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

         static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string apiUrl = @"http://localhost:3393/api/products";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.PostAsJsonAsync<Product>(apiUrl, new Product() { Id = 2, Name = "Jeans", Price = 200, Category =  "Clothing" });

    }
```

The postproduct method is never invoked, how to send this object to the controller ?

Method used for adding items:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct([FromBody]Product item)
    {
        item = repository.Add(item);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, what do you see in fiddler?  Have you enabled webapi tracing on the server?

Comment: I can see requests that originate from a form that I'm using no requests sent by the HttpClient are visible in Fiddler. 
I've also uploaded the api to: http://producttestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/products but none of the requests from the HttpClient reach that api either.

Comment: also, check the index.html of that url, thats the form I use to send objects through ajax, that one works so the api is ok.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you have somehow disabled accepting JSON as format for posting.  I was able to send the data to your endpoint and create new product using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  That is probably how your jQuery request is doing it.

Can you show your configuration code of your web api?  Do you change the default formatters?

Or you could send a form from HttpClient.  e.g.

```
    string apiUrl = "http://producttestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/products";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Id", "6"},
            {"Name", "Skis"},
            {"Price", "100"},
            {"Category", "Sports"}
        };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: the ajax method has 'dataType: "json"' defined. So that leads me to think that the controller still accepts JSON as data. I added the method that handles adding new objects to the list.

I would show the configuration code, is it a .cs file from the App_Start folder?   

Meanwhile, going to try the approuch you posted here.

Comment: I was able to use the PostAsJson method also using the code you gave and now it works. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: What we can do if we have a parameter like string array in the class. I can't set it to the Dictionary since  FormUrlEncodedContent is not accepting Dictionary<string, Object>